# Symfony2 - Having trouble setting up a query that loads the user selection from the sidebar

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tags, twig, tag-cloud

I'm trying to load posts from tags but thus far haven't been able to find a working solution for this.

Not sure if the problem is with the query or how it's being selected from the twig file. Using the repository code below gives me an empty array.

If the problem is the query how do you set it up to where it takes the user input from the sidebar to load the tag that in turn loads the right post?

[image]

**repository**

```
/**
 * @Route("/tag/{tag}", name="AcmeDemoBundle_tag")
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Page:tag.html.twig")
 */
public function getPostsByTags($tag)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->where('b.tags = :tag')
            ->setParameter('tag', $tag);

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

The twig file is loading the tags via tag weights in the controller see below:

**sidebar twig**

```
<p class="tags">
        {% for tag, weight in tags %}
        <span class="weight-{{ weight }}"><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag }) }}">{{ tag }}</a></span>
        {% else %}
    <p>There are no tags</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
```

**controller**

```
/**
 * @Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Page:sidebar.html.twig")
 */
public function sidebarAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $tags = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog')
            ->getTags();

        $tagWeights = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog')
            ->getTagWeights($tags);

        return array(
            'tags' => $tagWeights,
        );
    }

/**
 * @Route("/tag/{tag}", name="AcmeDemoFitnessBundle_tag")
 * @Template("AcmeDemoFitnessBundle:Page:tag.html.twig")
 */
public function tagAction($tag = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $tags = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Blog')
        ->getPostsByTags($tag);

    return array(
        'tags' => $tag,
    );
}
```

Selecting on a tag from the sidebar yields nothing, (an empty array) I'm not sure if it's a twig problem or how the doctrine query is setup.

Please help.

entity

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="text")
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the getPostsByTags function in the controller? If you want to know whether you are getting rows using results just print the results in the controller and check it. Once you have the results from the db showing it using twig will be easy

Comment: Updated with the getPostsByTags function. Basically I'm not getting back anything (empty array) when I dump $tags. That's the problem, not sure if the query is wrong and not taking account of the user selection of the tag?

Comment: Are you getting the $tag variable from the twig in the controller? Can you add the routing details for this action too?

Comment: The (sidebarAction) listed above is providing the 'tags' for the twig then in the twig (listed as sidebar twig in the question) a for loop ({% for tag, weight in tags %}) is providing the 'tag' variable which I am using to link the tags. (<span class="weight-{{ weight }}"><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag }) }}">{{ tag }}</a></span>)

Comment: This part works fine, as shown in the screen shot, it's the selecting of the tags in the sidebar which isn't bringing up anything.

Comment: What I asked was whether you are checked the clicked tag value inside the tagAction from the {{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag }) }} action or is the $tag variable itseld null

Comment: What I checked was $tags from inside the controller. Added a (var_dump($tags)die();) just before the return array in tagAction, then clicked on a tag from the sidebar which turned out to be null/empty array.

Comment: Thank you Manoj for taking some time to taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, how is the content of your tags field stored in the database?

In any case, it seems that you are storing your tags as a string in the database. This means that your query should look more like this:

```
public function getPostsByTags($tag)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.tags like :tag')
        ->setParameter('tag', '%'.$tag.'%');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

If you didn't want to store your tags as a string, but as a relation with another entity, you should create an association instead.

See [The doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) for more information! :)

Comment: Exactly it! The query was wrong. This is what I was missing, thank you Charles! And the tags were stored as a string if that answers your question.

Comment: Spent a day trying to figure this out, couldn't find anything! Cheers.